# Haskell Even Function?

Tags: haskell

This is probably a fairly obvious question, but I just can't figure it out.

I am trying to write a function that squares the even numbers in a list. When I try to run it, I am getting an error about my use of the even function. How can I fix this?

```
module SquareEvens where

squareEvens :: [Integer] -> [Integer]

squareEvens n = [ns * ns | ns <- n, even n]
```

Comment: the function works fine for me if you change 'even n' to 'even ns'

Comment: yep! that fixed it groovy! wow, duh.

Comment: On an unrelated note, by convention `ns` often indicates a list, and `n` indicates an element from that list. You might consider switching your `n` and `ns` to follow the common Haskell usage.

Comment: I went ahead and edited the question according to @kputnam's suggestion.

Comment: @groovy Please write your comment as an answer, so this question can be removed from the unanswered category

Comment: @Paul ...which means the code in the question doesn't produce an error, so the question doesn't make sense any more. I'm going to revert your changes and add the answers from groovy and kputnam as CW.

Comment: @dave4420 Hm, yes that is true ... why didn't I think of it? thanks for reverting

Comment: @Undreren why is it important for a question to be removed from the unanswered category?

Comment: @groovy I just thought that it should be marked as "answered" since was in fact _answered_. Makes sense, no?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code works fine if you change `even n` to `even ns`:

```
squareEvens n = [ns * ns | ns <- n, even ns]
```

But note that the convention is to use the plural to name the list and the singular to name an element from that list. So swap `n` and `ns` to follow idiomatic Haskell usage:

```
squareEvens ns = [n * n | n <- ns, even n]
```

Answer (score 7):

As you can see, it's easy to get variable names wrong. So why not do it without?

```
squareEvens = map (^2) . filter even
```

I think this is clearer than the comprehension. You can read it from right to left: Keep only the even numbers, then square them.